# Sent automated rejection but LinkedIn profile was viewed

Tags: rejection

I applied for a job recently and noticed that a senior manager from the department and another individual (in private mode) viewed my LinkedIn profile on Sunday.  I was sent an automated email on Monday saying that my background did not match. My profile matches my resume but does contain more jobs as I was told my resume needed to be shortened. Is it normal for a LinkedIn profile to be viewed by what appears to be manager after a resume passes through a job posting and then later become rejected?

Comment: How many people applied for the job? How well did your application meet the minimum requirements as measured by an automated screening system? These are factors you leave out totally yet may well answer your question that unless we worked for that company, how do we know what the answer is here?

Comment: There really isnt any way to tell outside of having a discussion with HR, which I would not suggest.

Comment: I am not sure how many people applied for the job.  I would assume that I matched the qualifications/ minimum requirements to be viewed on LinkedIn by a team member. I should have asked is that a normal HR protocol to be denined when they have made apparent that they've viewed your profile?

Comment: I don't get your question. How is it different from "A senior manager read my resume, but I got a rejection mail."? What is the relevance of "viewed my LinkedIn profile"?

Comment: @MaskedMan he's worrying that his resume not having some information in his linked in profile might have been interpreted as being deceptive.  Which is possible if IMO unlikely and in the general case would be slightly stupid on the part of the potential new employer:  A resume's intended to highlight relevant experience for a particular job; while a linked in profile is generic work history and not being subject to length limits can contain information not relevant to a particular job and a lot more information in general.

Comment: (OTOH if the OP fudged resume start/end dates to cover gaps from jobs only listed in linked in, the date fudging itself would be problematic in a way that not listing a short non-relevant job shouldn't be.)

Comment: @DanNeely Oh, I see, thanks. I had missed the "background did not match" in OP's post.

Comment: Why is it surprising that your profile was viewed? Isn't that what the LinkedIn profile is for?

Comment: @JobSeekerNYC Looking at your profile just means looking at your profile. That someone looked should be seen as a positive thing. Looking doesn't mean you'll get the job or even an interview though.

Comment: My resume is shorten to the past four relevant jobs that I have had. My linkedin profile is more in depth and list jobs that date back to my first year of grad school to showcase research experience. I did not think it appropriate to give longer than a two page resume to highlight every job I've had. The start and end dates of my employment match up with what is on my resume. I am questioning if they viewed my profile after receiving my resume and making a decision upon my LinkedIn profile.

Comment: @JobSeekerNYC Asking at which precise moment they made a decision is not answerable. Suppose you set up your LinkedIn profile to highlight exactly the same jobs as the CV you sent, and the same course of events occurred (they viewed it and then later sent a rejection). Well then, you may still be here asking why they rejected you. And the answer would still be unknown.

Comment: You are overthinking this...

Comment: It was very likely a canned response, not an automated one.

Answer (score 7):

> Could it have been my profile or just that my application was denied
>   through the automated system?

Most "automated systems" wouldn't just issue a denial on their own. Someone has to tell the system to deny your application before it will send an email.

It could easily be that your profile didn't match what they expected in applicants, and that's why you were rejected. Or that could be a coincidence.